# How to tell client I cant do any more changes till they pay invoice?

Tags: communication, contracting

I am new to freelancing. I have developed a project for a client. I am waiting for the final invoice to be settled - fixed price project. The client has requested revision changes 3 times. By revision changes I mean, I have presented the project to them and they have given me a list of changes to implement (this has occurred 3 times). Now I have been given a 4th list of revision changes.

I'm unsure how to phrase or communicate that I cannot do anymore change till my previous invoice has been paid. Can you provide some advice and/or examples?

Should I/can I simply say; I cannot perform your requested changes until the last invoice has been settled?

Comment: Did you agree on a price for the new "features" to be modified/implemented before or after they asked? Like: You: here's the final cut of the project. Them: could you do this and this? Change/add this? You: ???

Comment: Have you *asked* them to settle the invoice? If yes, what was their response?

Comment: "Should I/can I simply say; I cannot perform your requested changes until the last invoice has been settled? "  Yes, you can and you should!

Comment: What are the exact conditions for payment?  Is there actually a limit on how much time it takes before they need to pay, or is it just "I give you finished product, you give me money"?  Also, are these "revisions" just small tweaks to the basic behaviour, or are they actually new features, over and above the original requirements, being tacked on after the fact?

Comment: This video on client relationships might be helpful: https://youtu.be/6h3RJhoqgK8

Answer (score 16):

Things like that (when the invoice should be paid, how many rounds of revisions are possible and how much time the client has to inform you about them) should be agreed on in the contract signed before starting the project.

If they are there, you just say "according to the contract you need to pay me first".

If they aren't there you need to negotiate with this client and treat it as a lesson learnt for the future.

Answer (score 5):

If the client has given you four separate lists of required changes, then either (a) you completely missed the ball on the project, or (b) they're trying to get out of paying the last installment.

Refer the client back to your contract (you do have one, I hope?), and point out any relevant clauses for payment.

Never have more money/work at risk with a client than you're prepared to lose. And remember that until the client pays (because it's a section in the contract) or you supply a written release, you still own the copyright to the work you've done. So if the client refuses to pay you, you can legally refuse to let them use your work.

I've been there, done that, working far too hard to complete a contract when the client was a crook and had absolutely no intention of paying. We got nasty in the end, and got our money. They're no longer in business.